# Angular spirngboot-preflight

Tags: spring-boot, cors, angular7

1.In Spring boot I am adding `"spring-boot-starter-security"` dependency in pom.xml file and getting an error in angular console saying **preflight error**, even though I am overriding the method

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();

    }
}
```

2. From browser i can directly access  my data's by using link `http://localhost:8080/users/..`  and giving user id and password which are set by me in application.properties file.
3. But by using same user id and password i am not able to get data's form restlet-client(Similar app like Postman for testing API's).

**proxy.conf.js** file

```
module.exports = { "/myapi": { "target": "localhost:8080", "secure": false, "changeOrigin": true, "pathRewrite": { "^/myapi": "" } }
```

**HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService implements HttpInterceptor { constructor() { } intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){ let username='MSD' let password ='dummy' let basicAuthHeaderString = 'Basic '+ username + ':' + password; request=request.clone({ setHeaders : { Authorization : basicAuthHeaderString } }) return next.handle(request); } }
```

Anyone knows why this error is happening,please do sort out .

Comment: Hello Moni Shankar, Add below WebConfig class and try again and let me know the results

Comment: hi bro @PatelRomil thanks for ur solution... my problem got solved and it was related proxy.conf.js file in angular

Comment: @PatelRomil but bro in angular if add           providers: [
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass:HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService,
      multi: true 
   }     then getting CROS error...if u have any idea..please do share

Comment: if CORS issue is there you have to add a webconfig class at spring boot, please share proxy config and HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService to get more details

Comment: proxy.conf.js file----------
module.exports =
{
    "/myapi": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/myapi": ""
          }
    }

Comment: HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService.ts 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorBasicAuthService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
    let username='MSD'
    let password ='dummy'
    let basicAuthHeaderString = 'Basic '+ username + ':' + password;
    request=request.clone({
      setHeaders : {
          Authorization : basicAuthHeaderString
      }
    })
     return next.handle(request); 
  }
}

Comment: @PatelRomil do check if possible

Comment: Hello Moni Shankar, can you create the below class in spring boot and let me know the outcome

Comment: If CORS is the problem, open run command box(windows key + R - for windows) and paste this  "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security" and click ok. Then chrome will open in a new window. Running your program in this chrome window will solve the problem.(note- this is for chrome browser)

Comment: Hello @m-2127 It may work but it is not an ideal way to do that. Remember that client will open it in secure browser

Answer (score 0):

*What is Pre Flight?*

This pre-flight request (RequestMethod.OPTIONS) is made by some browsers as a safety measure to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server. Meaning the server understands that the method, origin and headers being sent on the request are safe to act upon.

---

*option 1: WebConfig for CORS*

You can create one WebConfig Class for CORS Origin Configuration so that we ***don't need to write `@CrossOrigin` at each and every controller.***

*WebConfig.java*

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "USERID");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ROLE");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

---

*option 2 application.properties*

```
# ENDPOINTS CORS CONFIGURATION (CorsEndpointProperties)
management.endpoints.web.cors.allow-credentials= # Whether credentials are supported. When not set, credentials are not supported.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers= # Comma-separated list of headers to allow in a request. '*' allows all headers.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods= # Comma-separated list of methods to allow. '*' allows all methods. When not set, defaults to GET.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins= # Comma-separated list of origins to allow. '*' allows all origins. When not set, CORS support is disabled.
management.endpoints.web.cors.exposed-headers= # Comma-separated list of headers to include in a response.
management.endpoints.web.cors.max-age=1800s # How long the response from a pre-flight request can be cached by clients. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
```

---

*option 3 `@CrossOrigin`:*

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://domain1.com"})
```